# Will JavaScript influence my search position in Google?

Tags: seo, google, javascript, search-results

I have a script which does some position fixes within my site - things like

```
$(".slider_text").css("paddingLeft", procentaj_stdr);
$(".slider_text").css("paddingTop", procentaj_slider/12);
```

There are less than 100 lines of JavaScript and jQuery code that make this corrections.

Should I worry about Google lowering my position in search results?

Comment: Why do you think this would affect your rankings in Google?

Comment: @JohnConde I've read on the Internet that the scripts that Google uses to crawl the webpage don't "like" javascript because they don't understand it

Comment: @HelloLili, maybe a decade ago... I recommend you read up to date advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**! There will be no specific influence in your Google SERP if you use JavaScript in your webpage. In older days Google was not that much smart to fetch dynamically generating contents, JavaScript and AJAX but now Google algorithm is very smart to Crawl and Index those contents.

> Historically, SEO recommendations have centered around having ‘plain
>   text’ content whenever possible. Dynamically generated content, AJAX,
>   and JavaScript links have been a detriment to SEO for the major search
>   engines. Clearly, that is no longer the case for Google. Javascript
>   links work in a similar manner to plain HTML links

This is the statement in Search Engine Land article titled [We Tested How Googlebot Crawls Javascript And Here What We Learned](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157). They tested 5 category of tests like

1. JavaScript Redirects
2. JavaScript Links
3. Dynamically Inserted Content
4. Dynamically Inserted Meta Data and Page Elements
5. An Important Example with rel=“nofollow”

All these cases were passed successfully and Google was able to fetch and index those contents just like other Plain Texts which means that there would be no change in Google SERP if you use JavaScript in your website.